# CSS is breaking on first load, gets corrected on hot reload

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

CSS on my site is breaking on first build load, but gets automatically corrected when i press command + s on code. Hotreload does the magic here.

On development environment, this issue could be tackle temporarily by making changes and command + s and undoing the same and command + s again. This will trigger a hotreload and ultimately rebundle all assets(including css) and it correctly loads the css on site.

But on staging or production we production build the program by,
`NODE_ENV=production IS_BUILDING_NEXTJS=1 next build src`
So can't hack there.

I have tried removing all the aliases from webpackConfig but it didn't work.

Below is my `next.config.js`

```
const withCSS = require("@zeit/next-css");
module.exports = withCSS({
  cssLoaderOptions: {
    url: false
  },
  // NextJS builds to `/src/.next` by default. Change that to `/build/app`
  distDir: "../build/app",
  webpack: (webpackConfig) => {
    webpackConfig.module.rules.push({
      test: /\.(gql|graphql)$/,
      loader: "graphql-tag/loader",
      exclude: ["/node_modules/", "/.next/"],
      enforce: "pre"
    });
    webpackConfig.resolve.alias.handlebars = 'handlebars/dist/handlebars.min.js';
    webpackConfig.module.rules.push({
      test: /\.mjs$/,
      type: "javascript/auto"
    });
    webpackConfig.resolve.alias["styled-components"] = "styled-components/dist/styled-components.browser.esm.js";
    return webpackConfig;
  }
});
```

Expecting the css should load correctly on the first load itself on every environment.

Currently, on development, it is loading correctly on hotreload. 
Hotreload doesn't feel right on staging/production.

Comment: You won't be having hotreload in production, will you?

Comment: Nope @IvanRubinson we can't provision a hotreload in production. Since its not a recommended practice to do so.

Comment: Have you verified that before hotreload the CSS assets are indeed broken? Maybe the browser window opens before the initial build of the CSS is done.

Comment: Yes @IvanRubinson the css was already broken beforehand. So it gets glitchy when the site is being loaded for the first time, during the loading process i see correct css gets loaded for about half second. But as soon as the loading process gets completed all you see is broken css until you hotreload.

Comment: So is just the website "broken" or is your actual css code incorrect? I'm pretty sure that css doesn't just break.

Comment: @Elias website's functionality like links, action buttons and so on works as expected. Also, found that there are some rendering issue which is ultimately causing css to break since it appears to be fine during the site loading process but breaks once site is loaded completely. 
I think it has to do something with this issue => [Document that you can't rely on React 16 SSR patching up differences](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/10591#issuecomment-344564375)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below fix worked, which will eliminate the re-render issue and CSS incorrectly applied on component. Got reference from [material-ui CSS not working on SSR issue](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/11790)

We would require to set `dangerouslyUseGlobalCSS` to `true`

```
generateClassName: createGenerateClassName({ dangerouslyUseGlobalCSS: true })
```

to the function `createPageContext()` in `src/getPageContext.js` file